# Longest increasing subset Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to create in Prolog to find longest increasing subset of entered list. For example, you enter list of [3,1,2] and the output is [1,2],

```
?- subset([3,1,2], X).
X = [1,2]
```

I have code which shows all the subsets of this list:

```
subset([],[]).
subset([_|X],Y):-subset(X,Y).
subset([A|X],[A|Y]):-subset(X,Y).
```

Can anyone help me to find just the longest increasing subset?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `[1,3,5,6,7]` to be the answer for `[4,1,3,8,9,5,6,7]`? IOW, do you really mean subsets, or just sublists, i.e. contiguous portions of the list?

If the latter is the case, you won't need subsets. The search is linear. If in a list `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` you find that `d > e` and the increasing sequence `[a,b,c,d]` stops, you don't need to restart the search from `b` now: the sequence will still break at `d`. You will just continue your search from `e`.

So, we'll just carry around some additional information during the search, viz. the current and the winning-so-far sub-sequences. And their lengths.

```
longest_incr([],0-[]).
longest_incr([A|B],RL-R):-                  % R is the result, of length RL
    longest_aux(B,[],0, [A],1, RL-R). 

longest_aux([],   Win,N, Curr,K, RL-R):- 
    ( K>N -> RL=K, reverse(Curr,R) ; RL=N, reverse(Win,R) ).
longest_aux([A|B],Win,N, Curr,K, RL-R):- Curr = [X|_], L is K,
    ( A>X -> longest_aux(B,Win, N, [A|Curr],L+1,RL-R)    % keep adding
    ; L>N -> longest_aux(B,Curr,K, [A],     1,  RL-R)    % switch the winner
    ;        longest_aux(B,Win, N, [A],     1,  RL-R)    % winner unbeaten 
    ).
```

If OTOH you really need the longest subset ... there's a contradiction there. A set can have its elements rearranged, so the longest subset of a given list will be

```
longset_subset(L,R):- sort(L,S), R=S.
```

Perhaps you mean the longest order-preserving sub-sequence, i.e. it is allowed to be non-contiguous. Then you can gather all solutions to your `subset` with `findall` or similar predicate, and analyze these results:

```
longest_subseq(L,R):- 
    findall( S, subset(L,S), X),
    maplist( longest_incr, X, Y),
    keysort( Y, Z), 
    last( Z, _Len-R).
```

The above has a lot of redundancy in it. We can attempt to improve its efficiency by only allowing the *increasing* subsequences:

```
incr_subseq([],[]).
incr_subseq([_|X],Y):- incr_subseq(X,Y).
incr_subseq([A|X],[A|Y]):- incr_subseq(X,Y), ( Y=[] ; Y=[B|_], A<B).
```

Now all the sub-sequences found by the above predicate will be increasing, so we can just take their `length`s:

```
lenlist(List,Len-List) :- length(List,Len).
longest_subseq(L,R):- 
    findall( S, incr_subseq(L,S), X),
    maplist( lenlist, X, Y),
    keysort( Y, Z), 
    last( Z, _Len-R).
```

Or, the linear searching `longest_incr` could be tweaked for a more efficient solution. Instead of maintaining just one winning sub-sequence, it would maintain all the relevant possibilities as it goes along the input list.

Comment: I would actually assume he means "longest increasing subsequence", based on his `subset`. There are plenty of algorithms for doing this. In his case, he could simply enumerate all increasing subsequences (that he has called subsets) and see which one is longest.

Comment: @Boris you mean contiguous, or non-contiguous? Based on his `subset`, perhaps the 2nd case?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence Non-contiguous, per definition. If it were contiguous it would be called substring, I would guess . Order however is important (hence the -sequence). Plenty of available algorithms out there.

Comment: @Boris yes, this seems the most logical. I do mention calling `findall` there... :)

Comment: Maybe you could give me some example from which I could learn how to create that longest_aux predicate? As I mentioned, I am still learning Prolog

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, would it be possible in prolog to realize something like this for finding longest increasing subsequence:

- You find all subsets of list
- Than you find, which of these subsets are increasing
- And then you search for the longest

If it's possible, how could I do that in Prolog?

Comment: for the list `X`, the answer `R` will satisfy `sort(X,R)`. Because sets are considered equal no matter what is the order of their elements. If you mean *sub-sequences*, i.e. containing elements in original order and perhaps from non-contiguous regions of the list, then it's exactly what this question is asking.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I tweaked your idea BTW - I test the sub-sequences for increasing-ness as they are being generated.